# JavaScript on resize and load, move element based on window width

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation, window-resize, window-load

I'm trying to move an element to an off canvas menu if the window width is less than 768px wide.

So far I have this:

```
<script>
    window.onresize = move_sidebar(event);
    window.onload = move_sidebar(event);
    function move_sidebar(event) {
        if(window.outerWidth > 768) {
            return;
        } else {
            console.log('resized or loaded');
            document.getElementById('offcanvas-menu').appendChild(document.getElementById('sidebar-content'));
        }

    }
</script>
```

When the window loads it works fine, the console log is shown and the element is moved, however, when I resize the window the event doesn't fire.

Unless I do:

```
window.onresize = function(event) { console.log('resizing'); };
```

This then logs each time the window is resized, I'm unable to figure out why there's a difference between the two.

I also need to move the element back to its original place if the width is greater than 768px, as long as it only exists in the offcanvas-menu element.

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT:**

I ended up fixing this with the following code:

```
<script>
    window.onresize = move_sidebar;
    window.onload = move_sidebar;
    function move_sidebar(event) {
        ele = document.getElementById('sidebar-content');
        if(window.outerWidth > 768) {
            if(ele.parentNode.id == 'offcanvas-menu') {
                document.getElementById('sidebar').appendChild(document.getElementById('sidebar-content'));
            }
            return;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('offcanvas-menu').appendChild(ele);
        }

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing as the event handler the **result** of you `move_sidebar` function after execution, instead of passing the function itself.

Your code should be:

```
window.onresize = move_sidebar;
window.onload   = move_sidebar;
```

The reason it works for you when the page loads is only because you have manually executed your function by mistake.

Comment: Ahh yes, you are correct! Thanks a lot, I'm still having difficulty moving the element back if the width is greater than 768px though, I've done a check for the parentNode.id, and if it matches offcanvas-menu I'm trying to appendChild to the sidebar-content but not having a much luck as of yet.

Comment: Solved the above issue now, thanks a lot for your help!